# Замена в тексте хештега на ссылку php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать функцию php с использованием регулярных
выражений, которая заменит в тексте хештеги вида #хештег
на ссылки `<a href="/?tagName=хештег">#хештег</a>`

Пример текста: Я люблю #футбол, #волейбол и #теннис.

```
function tagsToLinks($text) { // Данный пример не работает
    return preg_replace('/(#)(.+)(\s?)/Uuis', '<a href="/?tagName=$2">$1$2$3</a>', $text);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что собственно не работает? - https://regex101.com/r/Nmb7SZ/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```php
function tagsToLinks($text) {
    return preg_replace('/#(\S+)/u', '<a href="/?tagName=$1">$0</a>', $text);
}
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/PcZdoo/1). **Подробности**:

- `#` - символ `#`
- `(\S+)` - подмаска №1: один и более символов, отличных от пробельных.

В шаблоне замены `$0` ссылается на текст целого совпадения, а `$1` — на текст первой подмаски.